# Angular router navigate does not redirect after dynamically adding routes to router

Tags: angular

I am writing an angular frontend for a cms system. The pages are exposed over an api. I want to add the routes to my frontend, however I have had problems adding these before the router tries to resolve them.

I have now reached the point where I had added a wildcard route '**' to the routerModule which is always hit. This loads a component called the PageNavigateComponent which has a resolver. In this resolver I make sure that all the routes from the cms api are added to the the router.config. I use unshift so that the new routes are added before the wildcard route. Then in the constructor of the pageNavigateComponent I try to redirect to the url which the user typed.

```
this.router.navigate([this.currentUrl]);
```

However when I do this nothing happens.

If I hard code this route in the routerModule instead of adding it dynamically, then the redirect works. So I think it has something to do with adding the route dynamically. But if I log the router.config just before the navigate call, it looks just the same whether I add the route dynamically or hard code it.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I approaching the problem in completely the wrong way?

---

Edit 1: here is some code:

from app.routing.ts:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNavigateComponent,
    resolve: { loaded: PageNavigateResolver }
  }
];
```

from app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
]
```

here is the page.navigate resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class PageNavigateResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor (private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private router: Router) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('resolving for page navigate');

        return this.store.select(fromRoot.getRouteLoaded)
                .filter(isLoaded => isLoaded === true)
                .first();
    }
}
```

here is the code which loads the routes into the router.config:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoutingEffects {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions
    , private apiService: ApiPageService
    , private router: Router) { }

    /**
     * This effect makes use of the `startWith` operator to trigger
     * the effect immediately on startup.
     */
    @Effect()
    loadRoutes$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .startWith(new route.LoadRoutesAction())
        .debounceTime(500)
        .switchMap(() =>  this.apiService.getRoutes())
        .take(1)
        .map(routes => {
            for (let route of routes) {
                let myRoute = route as Route;
                console.log('route from DB is ', myRoute.Path, myRoute.Type);
                this.router.config.unshift({
                    path: myRoute.Path, 
                    component: mapper.getComponent(myRoute.Type),
                    data: [{secure: myRoute.Secure}],
                    resolve: { loaded: resolvers.getResolver(myRoute.Type) }
                }); 
            }
            return new route.LoadRoutesSuccessAction(<Route[]>routes);
        })
}
```

Here is the PageNavigateComponent:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'lac-page-navigate',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: '<p>page navigate is Loading... {{currentUrl}}</p>'
})
export class PageNavigateComponent {
    currentUrl: string = '';

    constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>, route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
        console.log('hello from page-navigate');
        this.currentUrl = '/' + route.snapshot.url.join('/');

        console.log('snapshot url is: ', this.currentUrl);
        this.router.navigate([this.currentUrl]);
    }
}
```

---

Edit 2: Here is the console.trace,

```
console.trace(this.router.navigate([this.currentUrl]));

PageNavigateComponent @ page-navigate.ts:34  
createClass @ core.es5.js:10788  
createDirectiveInstance @ core.es5.js:10621  
createViewNodes @ core.es5.js:11971  
createRootView @ core.es5.js:11876  
callWithDebugContext @ core.es5.js:13007  
debugCreateRootView @ core.es5.js:12468  
ComponentFactory_.create @ core.es5.js:9812  
ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create @ core.es5.js:3427  
ViewContainerRef_.createComponent @ core.es5.js:10012  
RouterOutlet.activateWith @ router.es5.js:5345  
ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet @ router.es5.js:4527  
ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes @ router.es5.js:4508  
(anonymous) @ router.es5.js:4444  
ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes @ router.es5.js:4444  
ActivateRoutes.activate @ router.es5.js:4418  
(anonymous) @ router.es5.js:4035  
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:96  
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236  
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185  
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:143  
InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:49  
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:57  
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:45  
MapOperator.call @ map.js:54  
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:42  
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22  
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:130  
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:127  
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:110  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:143  
InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
ReduceSubscriber._complete @ reduce.js:119  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete @ mergeMap.js:165  
InnerSubscriber._complete @ InnerSubscriber.js:30  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
Subscriber._complete @ Subscriber.js:132  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
Subscriber._complete @ Subscriber.js:132  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
LastSubscriber._complete @ last.js:111  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
MergeAllSubscriber.notifyComplete @ mergeAll.js:105  
InnerSubscriber._complete @ InnerSubscriber.js:30  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
Subscriber._complete @ Subscriber.js:132  
Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114  
FirstSubscriber._emitFinal @ first.js:136  
FirstSubscriber._emit @ first.js:118  
FirstSubscriber._next @ first.js:97  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
FilterSubscriber._next @ filter.js:88  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next @ distinctUntilChanged.js:103  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55  
BehaviorSubject.next @ BehaviorSubject.js:44  
(anonymous) @ state.js:26  
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236  
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185  
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
ScanSubscriber._tryNext @ scan.js:115  
ScanSubscriber._next @ scan.js:102  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
WithLatestFromSubscriber._next @ withLatestFrom.js:113  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
Notification.observe @ Notification.js:32  
ObserveOnSubscriber.dispatch @ observeOn.js:50  
AsyncAction._execute @ AsyncAction.js:111  
QueueAction.execute @ QueueAction.js:33  
AsyncScheduler.flush @ AsyncScheduler.js:36  
QueueAction.schedule @ QueueAction.js:27  
Scheduler.schedule @ Scheduler.js:43  
ObserveOnSubscriber.scheduleMessage @ observeOn.js:54  
ObserveOnSubscriber._next @ observeOn.js:57  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55  
BehaviorSubject.next @ BehaviorSubject.js:44  
Store.next @ store.js:35  
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:236  
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185  
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
OuterSubscriber.notifyNext @ OuterSubscriber.js:19  
InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
DoSubscriber._next @ do.js:88  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
TakeSubscriber._next @ take.js:80  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ switchMap.js:124  
InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83  
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89  
onLoad @ http.es5.js:1205  
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:414  
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4116  
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:413  
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:181  
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @echonax I added my code now, tell me if you need any more information. would a console trace be helpful?

Comment: Yeah the trace would be definitely helpful

Comment: @echonax the console.log('snapshot url is: ', this.currentUrl); line prints whatever is in the url bar, for example when my url bar says http://localhost:4200/home/register then the console.log prints snapshot url is:  /home/register